# Why is this code not displaying output on the textbox?

Tags: c#

I am beginning with C#. When I run the following code and click the generate button the output does not appear in the textbox. Why is this? I am calling the function palendrome and its not updating the textbox.  What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? What do I need to fix. I don't see the error. Please help. :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PalendromeChecker
{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int num;
    int count;
    static int result;
    int setPalendromeValue;
    int copyCount;


    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        copyCount = count;

        if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out count))
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = "Please enter a positive number within the range.";
        }
        else if (count < 0 || count > 100)
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = "Please enter a positive number within the range.";
        }

    }

    public static int palendrome(int num)
    {
        int temp = num; ;
        int r;
        int rv = 0;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            r = num % 10;
            rv = rv * 10 + r;
            num /= 10;

        }
        if (rv == temp)
        {
            result = temp;
            return temp;

        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }



    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (copyCount != 0)
        {
            string resultInString = result.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = resultInString;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        //MessageBox.Show(this.textBox1.Text);



        if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("This is a number only field");
            //return;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = "Please enter a positive number within the range.";

        }
        else if (num < 0 || num > 1000000000)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input needs to be between 0 and 1,000,000,000");
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = "Please enter a positive number within the range.";
        }


    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int palendromeValue;

        while (count != 0)
        {
            palendromeValue = palendrome(num);
            count--;


        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? What do I need to fix. I don't see the error. Please help.`  - These don't add any value to the question, just one would have been enough

Comment: Did you debug the code?  What part of the code do you think can cause the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not generating any input on the textbox because your function `palendrome` is not generating in anyway output on any of textbox1 to textbox3.

Try this:

```
textBox1.Text = "output"; //Whatever output you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show result in `textBox3` the code to update it's `text` property should be inside button click handler, not in text changed handler.

Also `while (count != 0)` or `while (copyCount != 0)` are like infinite loops (almost). They are going to make your form unresponsive. You need to avoid those.